# Trouble installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 2009

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, iso, macbook-pro

Installed using an ISO on a usb stick. Followed basic YouTube tutorial. The installation process is going just fine until I restart my computer after the installation is complete and I remove the usb. I get the Ubuntu loading screen, and then it just goes blank. I’m supposed to see the login page. Any suggestions?

I tried reinstalling with the option “automatically log in”. Now, after the Ubuntu loading screen I get the pink jellyfish wallpaper (instead of a blank screen). However it’s only the wallpaper. There’s no control to be had here, no mouse or anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try using another ubuntu version like Xenial (Ubuntu Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS) or Zesty (Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus).
Hope this helps - Jaicob

Comment: I actually installed Linux Mint no problem. Is Xenial or Zesty better? I plan to use it for recording through Logic Pro, if it runs fast enough. It used to run just fine 5 years ago, fingers crossed!

Comment: @BrandonStumpf You're better off with a supported version of Mint than with an unsupported version of Ubuntu.